# Examples of $T_0, T_1, T_3, T_4$ and Hausdorff spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

What could be simple examples of $T_0$, $T_1$, $T_3$, $T_4$ and Hausdorff ($T_2$) topological spaces?

Comment: Any metric space is Hausdorff.

Comment: Do you already have some examples to start with?  Are you looking for something simpler than what you already have? (Some context would help.)  Or do you just want answers to generate a big list of examples?  Googling things like `example t0 space` will lead to websites with examples.

Comment: @Greta: are the examples you have too difficult and you are looking for simpler ones? Can you post some of the ones you might have found and why those are not sufficient or how they are confusing you? Regards

Comment: Actually I have only definitions of these spaces (separation axioms) and no examples, so I tried to google it, to find really simple ones as for beginner. The answer I got helped me with $T_0$, $T_1$ and Hausdorff spaces, but I'm still struggled with $T_3$ and $T_4$. Is simpler example of $T_3$ than this one http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17371/regular-spaces-that-are-not-completely-regular ? :)

Answer (score 3):

The [Sierpiński space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) is the simplest possible $T_0$ space that is not $T_1$. The [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) on $\Bbb N$ is the simplest possible $T_1$ topology that is not $T_2$. The discrete topology on any set is $T_2$.